# Invalid JSON file for DeploymentConfig for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, openshift, kubectl, openshift-enterprise

I have this JSON file which was converted from YAML:

```
{
  "kind": "DeploymentConfig",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "cdt-cae-deployment"
  },
  "spec": {
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "name": "cdt-cae"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "app_version": "latest"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "cdt-cae",
            "image": "containers.nabisco.com/cdt-org/cdt-dev:__IMAGETAG__",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 8080,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "APP_NAME",
                "value": "cdt-cae"
              },
              {
                "name": "CISCO_LC",
                "value": "dev"
              },
              {
                "name": "OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME",
                "value": "cdtdev"
              },
              {
                "name": "OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT",
                "value": "27058"
              },
              {
                "name": "OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST",
                "value": "secret stuff here"
              },
              {
                "name": "OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "secretKeyRef": {
                    "name": "refapp-secret",
                    "key": "mongodb-password"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "NOTIFICATIONS_CLIENT_SECRET",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "secretKeyRef": {
                    "name": "refapp-secret",
                    "key": "notifications-client-secret"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "name": "podinfo",
                "mountPath": "/etc/metadata",
                "readOnly": false
              }
            ],
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
            "securityContext": {
              "capabilities": {},
              "privileged": false
            }
          }
        ],
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "podinfo",
            "downwardAPI": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "path": "labels",
                  "fieldRef": {
                    "fieldPath": "metadata.labels"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "path": "annotations",
                  "fieldRef": {
                    "fieldPath": "metadata.annotations"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst"
      }
    },
    "replicas": 3,
    "selector": {
      "name": "cdt-cae"
    },
    "triggers": [
      {
        "type": "ConfigChange"
      }
    ],
    "strategy": {
      "type": "Rolling",
      "rollingParams": {
        "updatePeriodSeconds": 1,
        "intervalSeconds": 1,
        "timeoutSeconds": 120
      }
    }
  }
}
```

unfortunately this is invalid JSON - I get this message:

[image]

Does anyone know what's wrong with the config? It looks like it's actually valid JSON, only that perhaps the schema is wrong..

Don't mind this just adding more details
Don't mind this just adding more details
Don't mind this just adding more details
Don't mind this just adding more details
Don't mind this just adding more details
Don't mind this just adding more details
Don't mind this just adding more details
Don't mind this just adding more details
Don't mind this just adding more details

Comment: Are you sure when you pasted it into the field that you didn't include some funny non visible unicode character or perhaps a unicode BOM marker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
<value> expected, unexpected end of file
```

means that the thing processing the JSON thinks that the terminating } is missing.

The JSON quoted in the question is fine, but it's been changed from the original because of the secret fields. Maybe the secret has an unescaped quote?

Comment: ah good thinking, that could be that the secret fields have a problematic character